# Add To cart Button in articles magento not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have a problem with the <kbd>add to cart</kbd> button in my magento store version community. When you try to add articles and click the button it doesn't work.

Here is the link of the issue: 
http://masluz.panamerik.net/ilunimacion-automotriz/gabinete-ice-2x24w-magg.html

my file  view.phtml

```
    <div class="product-shop">
        <div class="product-name">
            <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
        </div>

        <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
            <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

        <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
            <div class="add-to-box">
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                    <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
        <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <div class="add-to-box">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
            <div class="short-description">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>

    </div>

    <div class="product-img-box">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
    </div>

    <div class="clearer"></div>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

    productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            // Remove custom datetime validators
            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                }
            }

            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
//]]>
</script>
</div>

<div class="product-collateral">

        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: don't link to your code. Include the relevant parts of the code in your question

Comment: Im use magento, i dont know where is the code of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you click it, the console receives the following error:

`TypeError: productAddToCartForm is undefined`

You are missing the `productAddToCartForm` function which is a standard Magento JS function used to add the product to the cart.  This is an issue with your custom theme.

Your custom theme is most likely rewriting the file **view.phtml** which is used on the product detail pages.

1. Look in:  **app/design/frontend/base/design/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**
2. The `productAddToCartForm` function is defined in this phtml file, you will see something like this:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
       var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
       productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
           if (this.validator.validate()) {
               var form = this.form;
               var oldUrl = form.action;

               if (url) {
                  form.action = url;
               }
               var e = null;
               try {
                   this.form.submit();
               } catch (e) {
               }
               this.form.action = oldUrl;
               if (e) {
                   throw e;
               }

               if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                   button.disabled = true;
               }
           }
       }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

       productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
           if(this.validator) {
               var nv = Validation.methods;
               delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
               delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
               delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
               // Remove custom datetime validators
               for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                   if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                       delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                   }
               }

               if (this.validator.validate()) {
                   if (url) {
                       this.form.action = url;
                   }
                   this.form.submit();
               }
               Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
           }
       }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
   //]]>
   </script>
   ```
3. Now open up the file that is rewriting the **view.ptml** file, located in your custom theme directory: **app/design/frontend/[theme_scope]/[theme_name]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**
   (Note: **[theme_scope]** and **[theme_name]** should be the folders for your theme).
4. Paste the `<script>` code containing the `productAddToCartForm` function back into your theme's **view.phtml** file.
5. Save the file, clear & flush all Magento caches.

If done correctly, the function should not be restored and appear in your page's source markup.  You can verify by viewing the html source of your page and checking if the function is defined.

Comment: Why its happend? can help me please?

Comment: Because your custom theme removed the function.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution on how to restore the function.  Your custom theme is most likely rewriting the view.phtml file and not including the addToCart functions Magento requires.

Comment: Not working :/, have other solution please?, it is make me crazy ;//

Comment: HERE IS MY VIEW.PHTML

Comment: The problem IS THE SAME.  Look at your HTML source code and search for the function `productAddToCart`.  It does not exist.  Why?  Because the template being used for that page does not include it.  The page might be using a different phtml file.  If you don't know which template files are being loaded, turn on Template Path hints which will tell you.  Here are the instructions: https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-

Comment: Axel i have turn on the paths now can help me?, sorry for this issues but very thanks for u help i hope can u help me, you are my salvation, thanks again.

Comment: I've told you exactly what the issue is.  You cannot expect me to debug it for you.  The function is missing from the page.  You need to determine why.  If you do not have the experience to do basic debugging of your theme I recommend hiring a professional to do it for you.